# Spectral radius of $I-KH$, where $K$ is a Kalman gain

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kalman-filter, spectral-radius

I have noticed numerically that the spectral radius of $I-KH$, where $K$ is a Kalman gain, is less than or equal to 1. In other words, for some symmetric positive definite matrices $R$ and $C$, and another matrix $H$, is the spectral radius of $I - CH^T(HCH^T + R)^{-1}H$ less than or equal to 1?

In the scalar case, it is clearly true that $1 - ch^2/(h^2 c+r) 
\leq 1$ for $c>0$, $r>0$, and the inequality is strict when $h\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the spectral radius of $I-KH$ is not guaranteed to be less or equal to 1. However, a spectral radius less than or equal to 1 implies the filter will be stable.

In other words, if the spectral radius is less than 1, the covariance matrix will not grow unbounded. This makes sense as the spectral radius is the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues; thus, the components of $P$ along the eigenvectors of $I-KH$ should be decreased in magnitude.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am not sure that this is true. I have only seen the condition for stability be on the spectral radius of the matrix $(I - KH)A$, where $A$ is the dynamics, since this is what controls the error dynamics rather than $I-KH$ (see, e.g., Eq. 12 in https://laurentlessard.com/teaching/me7247/lectures/lecture%2012%20-%20steady-state%20Kalman%20filter.pdf).

At least in my numerical experiments, It seems that the spectral radius of $I - KH$ is always less than or equal to 1, which is obvious in the scalar case. Can we find a counterexample in the matrix case?

Comment: @Hypercube I don't see why the dynamics would be needed because in the posterior computation you multiply the priori on the left by $I-KH$, which should "decrease" the covariance in a general sense. I would expect $I-KH$ to have an eigenvalue greater than 1 if the uncertainty in the measurements have a very large covariance or if the states are unobservable, but I suggest trying it out to see. I would be curious to see your result.